# Dedekind zeta function of a splitting field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, zeta-functions

Given an irreducible separable polynomial with coefficients in a number field $K$, what, if anything, can one deduce about the Dedekind zeta function of its splitting field only knowing the polynomial?

What if we restrict our coefficients to $\mathcal{O}_K$, or even $\mathbb{Z}$?

Does knowing the Galois group of the splitting field tell us anything about the zeta function?

Comment: If you "know" the polynomial then you certainly also know the splitting field, so you "know"  everything about the Dedekind zeta function. Perhaps you could be more precise about what you are trying to do, and what type of things about the Dedekind zeta function you want to know or compute or etc.

Comment: I suppose it is somewhat vague question. I'm interested in whether you can compute things like the structure of the Euler factors, the order of the pole at s=1, the existence of non-trivial zeroes, etc knowing only the coefficients of the polynomial, without having to compute the number field and its prime ideals, etc. I would guess that there isn't much you can say without having to find the roots, but I'm interested to know what, if any, structure can be determined only from the coefficients and symmetries of the polynomial

Comment: For a number field $K$, let $\widetilde{K}$ be the Galois closure of $K/\mathbf Q$. A prime $p$ is unramified in $\widetilde{K}$ if and only if it is unramified in $K$ (since $\widetilde{K}$ is a composite of fields all isomorphic to $K$) and a prime splits completely in $\widetilde{K}$ if and only if it splits completely in $K$. If $p$ is unramified in $K$ then $f_p(\widetilde{K}/\mathbf Q)$ is the lcm of all $f(\mathfrak p_i|p)$ where $\mathfrak p_i\mid p$ in $\mathcal O_K$. Can you translate these properties into statements about Euler factors of zeta-functions?